# Using Power Automate I need to perform a HTTP request on a site that is protected by Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, power-automate

I need to perform a HTTP request to a site that is hosted In an Azure App Service. This site has Azure Ad authentication enabled. The HTTP request will be performed by a MS flow. I have attempted to use basic authentication, but this fails. I am now looking at an Azure app registration to get access to the site, however I'm having issues with this too. Does anyone have any suggestions on the best approach?

Cheers

Comment: Hi, may I know which grant flow do you want to use ?

Comment: And could you please share a screenshot of the MS flow which you did ? If there is error message, please share the error message too.

Comment: Hi Hury, I'm not sure what you mean by "which grant flow". This is a very basic flow which is using a HTTP connector. When using basic authentication I get the following response "You do not have permission to view this directory or page.". I have setup an App registration, but this gives me the same response as basic authentication.

Comment: As you mentioned you are looking at Azure app registration to get access to the site, so I think you need to choose a grant type(such as client_credential or username/password or...).

Comment: I have created an App registration, but I don't understand what I need to do to give this registration access to the site. The site is hosted in an App service which has it's authentication set to "Log in with Active Directory". Are you able to provide me with some details on how this registration will get access to the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to some test, I reproduced your issue. When you enable authentication of your app service, you need to click "**Azure Active Directory**" under "**Authentication Providers**" and register a app in your azure ad(If you do not do any other operation, the name of app registered in ad should be same as you app service. Shown like below screenshot).
[image]

Then you can use "Active Directory OAuth" as Authentication type in your "HTTP" action.
[image]

You can go to your azure ad and click "**App registrations**", find the app name in it. And then you can find the "Tenant id", "Client ID". You also need to new a client secret like below screenshot.
[image]

The `Audience` in "HTTP" action also comes from your registration app, the `Audience` is "Application ID URI" in the page below:
[image]